# How to correctly pass (mutable) objects using ROS-SMACH FSM

Tags: python, multithreading, serialization, ros, mutable

I've been struggling with this question for a while now. My question is very specific so please don't post a link to the ROS-tutorial page with the "***!Note:***" paragraph showing how to pass mutable objects (unless you show me something I have missed). I would like to know if anyone has been able to correctly pass mutable objects back and forth in SMACH states, without encountering any errors.

I wrote a particularly simple and useless program to explain what I am attempting to do. I could post the code of this example (unfortunately however, not surprisingly to those that have used SMACH before, it is a long piece of code). So for now I will just try my best to explain it and include a [[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oktAg.png)] to an image of my example. I created two python scripts. Each script contains a single class and object of that class (with some basic methods). I create a publisher and subscriber in each script, one of the scripts sends messages (talks) while the other script listens to (hears) the messages. At the end the talker flags both FSMs to shutdown. If anyone would like the full code example let me know...

Code snippet below showing smach states and transitions:

```
# begin sm
with sm:
    smach.StateMachine.add('LOAD', loadFSM(), 
                           transitions={'LOADED':'SENDMSG'})
    smach.StateMachine.add('SENDMSG', startMSG(),
                           transitions={'SENT':'SENDMSG',
                                        'ENDING':'END'})
    smach.StateMachine.add('END', stopFSM(),
                           transitions={'DONE':'complete',
                                        'ERRED':'incomplete'})
```

Code snippet below showing a smach state (loadFSM):

```
class loadFSM(smach.State):
    def __init__(self):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes=['LOADED'],
                            output_keys=['talker_obj'],
                            input_keys=['talker_obj'])
        # Initialise our talker object
        self.talker = Talk()
    def execute(self, userdata):
        rospy.loginfo("talker state: Loading fsm")
        self.talker.init_publish()
        self.talker.init_subscribe()
        userdata.talker_obj = self.talker
        return 'LOADED'
```

The errors I receive (using Ubuntu 14.04, ROS indigo and python 2.7, not too sure but I believe the same errors occur in kinetic as well) only occur during state transitions and of course the introspective server does not work (does not show state transitions). The errors are;

**1. "Exception in thread sm_introViewer:status_publisher:"**

**2. "Could not execute transition callback: Traceback (most recent call 
    last):   File

        "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smach/container.py",

        line 175, in call_transition_cbs    cb(self.userdata,
        self.get_active_states(), *args)"**

I also need to add, that my simple finite state machine example actually works and completes successfully, even my project's 2 larger FSMs complete. However, when the FSM has many states like in my project, sometimes my simulations fail. I would like to know from anyone who has used SMACH extensively if they think these errors are the cause or if they know for a fact that I am not passing the object correctly between states.

Thanks in Advance,

Tiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems in the past. If I remember correctly, `userdata` can only handle basic types (int, string, list, dict, ...) but not arbitrary objects.
I solved it by passing the objects to the constructor of state classes, instead of using the userdata, i.e. something like:

```
class myState(smach.State):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes=['foo'], ...)
        self.obj = obj
    ...
```

and then initialize like follows:

```
obj = SomeClass()
with sm:
    smach.StateMachine.add('MY_STATE', myState(obj), 
                           transitions={'foo':'bar'})
```

It is not so nice as it circumvents the userdata concept but it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot luator! Sorry I'm only getting back to you now but I was busy with other work. Anyway, the method you outlined seems to work on the small example code I made! That is really awesome, although it might not be perfect it definitely works way better! I will now check out if the introspection server also works with this method. But I guess the biggest challenge will be to see if two massive SMACH FSMs work as well! I marked your answer as correct! I hope more people take note of this! It is a really annoying issue... Thanks again, Tiz.

Comment: I think you will not be able to monitor objects passed like this with the introspection server (it only knows about the `userdata`).

Comment: As a side note: If this answer fully resolves your question, please mark it as accepted (clicking the green check mark below the voting arrows). This is different from upvoting, as it clearly indicates that the problem is solved.

Comment: Hehe thanks. I did notice the green tick but I thought up voting automatically counted as accepted. As for the introspection server, I knew that not using userdata would have this effect. But it use to completely crash before and not even show state changes. Now its fine :)

Comment: Glad I could help.